# Problems while installing Python 3 on El Capitan

Tags: macos, homebrew, python

I'm using `homebrew` as my package manager. While installing `python3` with `brew install python3` I am getting the following error

```
class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
```

I've tried the steps outlined in [homebrew Troubleshooting](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.md) but the problem still exists. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Which version of macOS and Xcode are you using?

Comment: I am using El Capitan and Xcode 8.2

Comment: Not sure if you ever solved this issue. I reported it here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/9229

Comment: not quite solved it,i had to reinstall a fresh copy of el capitan again

Answer (score 2):

Once you have determined that it's not a `homebrew` problem using their troubleshooting guide my first suspicion would be that you are picking up the wrong version of the `enum` module. Make sure you are not setting `PYTHONPATH` anywhere (`echo $PYTHONPATH` at the command line will tell you) and try again.

The other possibility I would check is that you are running the right version of Python. `which python` should return `/usr/bin/python` (the version Apple installs), if not then you might want to check your PATH shell variable and temporarily set it to something else.

Comment: should the PYTHONPATH point to python 3.x or 2.x ?
I read it's recommended to say cmd 'python3' with python 3.x  and cmd 'python' with python 2.x

Comment: I can't make a recommendation on this because I use the Anaconda install of Python, not the home-brew one. I have PYTHONPATH pointing only to PyObjC so that it is picked up but nothing else from the Apple install of Python.

`
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC"
`

Comment: Why should `which python` point to the system Python? What if it points to a version installed via Homebrew? What is the correct way to install Python 3.x alongside the 2.x Homebrew version in this case?

Comment: The person asking the question had installed python3 with homebrew. Therefore, for the sake of the system, `python` should be python 2, the system one. 

If you're installing python 2 and 3 with homebrew then `which python` should point to the homebrew python 2 and python3 should point to python 3.

Comment: Hmm, but even when I have Homebrew Python 2, and `python` pointing to it, I get this error. (Btw you forgot the @slhck, just came here again by accident.)

Comment: @TonyWilliams everything was ok,no `PYTHONPATH` and am using a right version of python2 `/usr/local/bin/python` of which i know this is not the cause of the problem.NOTE, i have a new installation of el capitan and repeated the python 2 & 3 installation and everything worked fine. i still  have the previous installation of which i still can't figure out why the problem occurred with it since the steps of installation a 100% same!